# css select element that is not folllowed by the same class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Need to select element that is not followed by the same class, last-of-type is not good because it selects only the last element, but I need to select all elements that are not followed by the same, here is the example:

```
<div class ="the_class"> A </div>
<div class ="the_class"> B </div>
<div class ="the_class"> C </div>
<div class ="other_class"> D </div>
<div class ="the_class"> E </div>
<div class ="the_class"> F </div>
<div class ="the_class"> G </div>
```

I need to select C, and G.

Comment: You can't do that at the current css specs

Comment: the class name is known, just that the next element must have different class

Comment: no it selects the other class

Comment: Turnip answer is fine.  @Botond: When the class name is unknown, then it's not a robust way. What do you want to do?   https://jsfiddle.net/krocon/sgxqnd23/

Comment: @Marc no the OP wants to select the class before the change, it's not possible currently with css

Comment: If you don't mind the HTML being reversed, there is one way... https://jsfiddle.net/L93xd0bp/1/ . Not ideal.